# Suitescript RESTlet data get Error Empty JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have issue using POST Function, I want to transform Transfer Order to Item Receipt, But when I tried to execute the script, it failed with error  **"org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Empty JSON string (INVOCATION_WRAPPER$sys#24"**.

Anyone can help me about my issue ?

Here is my Suitescript Code :

```
    function postData (receiptItem) {
    doValidation([receiptItem.recordtype], ['recordtype'], 'POST');

        if (receiptItem.recordtype == 'transferorder') {

            var recordId = [];
            var recStr = [];

                var objRecord = record.transform({
                        fromType: record.Type.TRANSFER_ORDER,
                        fromId: 131,             // transfer Order internalid 
                        toType: record.Type.ITEM_RECEIPT,
                        defaultValues: {
                        customform: '433'}
                    });

                    var itemReceiptId = objRecord.save({
                                enableSourcing: false,
                                ignoreMandatoryField: false
                        });

                    recordId.push(itemReceiptId)    

                    log.debug({
                        "title": "[success] recordId: ",
                        "details": recordId
                    });

                    var recLoad = record.load({
                            type: receiptItem.recordtype,
                            id: recordId.getValue('internalid')
                    });

                    recStr.push({
                        use_form: recLoad.getText('customform'),
                        tran_id: recLoad.getValue('tranid'),
                        tran_date: recLoad.getValue('trandate'),
                        tran_from: recLoad.getValue('transferlocation'),
                        tran_to: recLoad.getValue('location'),
                        tran_ord_id: recLoad.getvalue('createdfrom'),
                        tran_memo: recLoad.getValue('memo')
                    });

                    log.debug({
                        "title": "recStr",
                        "details": recStr
                    });

                return recStr;
        }
}
    return {
        post: postData
    };
});
```

Comment: You'll need to share the request you're sending to the Restlet as well.

Comment: the request is :: Script : 2269
deploy : 1
recordtype : transferorder

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error, very likely some misplaced bracket.

Comment: I don't know what I miss in my script, can you tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are posting valid JSON and that the content type is set on your request

Comment: can you tell me a valid JSON that can I posting ?

Comment: any valid json should go through. we see this error when we do not have the correct content type sent to netsuite

Comment: you also need to log your context obj (receiptItem) to see if onPost is even being triggered

Answer (score 0):

You must send data as JSON. if empty or no data then send {} at least in POST as ContentType is Application/JSON. ECMA Standard. The error message clearly states that "Empty JSON string".

Then try this in Postman tool.